# How to remove images corresponding to a column when removing the column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am using rails 4.2.1, ruby 2.3.0p0 and carrierwave(0.11.0) in my project. Currrently I have a model Product with image column. Now, I want to save multiple images for same product. So I have created a new model ProductImage and used following code

```
Product.all.each do |prdct|
  if prdct.image.present?
    @photo = prdct.product_images.create!(image: prdct.image)
    prdct.remove_image!
  end
end
remove_column :products, :image
```

But the image saved in product/image folder is not getting removed. How can I remove the image after moving it under ProductImage model

Comment: Perhaps `product.image.destroy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `prdct.remove_image!` you have to save (`prdct.save`) the object so that it can be removed.

If you want to the delete the folder as well, you'll have to do something like this:

```
def remove_image_directory
 FileUtils.remove_dir("#{Rails.root}/path/to/folder/", force: true)
end
```

And call this method after deleting the image.

From the docs:
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#removing-uploaded-files

Comment: It worked. Image is deleted but the folder is not getting deleted. Can we delete the folder also?

Comment: @CR7 Updated my answer.